# Axios in vuejs sometimes gives me an error using wamp

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, wamp

I've a problem with my wamp and spa. When I go to my page, sometimes everything goes right, sometimes I get the 500 (Internal Server Error). I have multiple axios requests and some of them run and sometimes they don't (random). I don't have this problem on a live server.

I don't really know where the problem comes from. So I'll say that I have wampserver 3.1.7_x64 and show you on of my axios piece of code.

```
fetchOneGift(idToFetch)
        {
            return axios.get('/gifts/' + idToFetch)
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })     
        },
```

Edit :

Error from laravel logs :

[2019-05-23 17:01:13] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified.

It is specified though. I've run the "php artisan key:generate" command at the beginning of my project.

Comment: What's in error response body? In laravel.log? We can't predict the problem...

Comment: Sorry didnt know where to start with the problem @Tarasovych

Answer (score 0):

> No application encryption key has been specified

error means you have to set `APP_KEY` in the `.env`.

Try `php artisan key:generate` in console.

Comment: I've written that I had done it. It's not the problem.